# Why is my log4net Date Modified not updating?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, log4net

I have a .net 6 C# Windows service, and am using log4net to generate logfiles showing its working & what its doing. The logfiles work OK and are being populated as expected. We arent going to change to a different logfile solution, as this integrates with other services.

My problem is that despite the log4net file being updated, viewing the file in Windows Explorer (its Win 2012R2 server), the DATE MODIFIED doesnt update. If I stop the service, the date updates. Also if I just right-click the file in Explorer, the date updates, so I think its a Windows issue. Ive seen several forums saying Windows doesnt update Date Modified except under certain circumstances to minimise disk activity. I need the date to update, as we check this date as part of system monitoring.

I'd prefer not to have to implement any new code, but can do so if really necessary.

Heres my log4net config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\Logs\MyService.log" />
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10000KB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Thank you

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with a process that has nothing to do with log4net (this is plain python) so I suspect your code is not to blame. Will follow in case we get a solution.